# 'Correct' unsigned integer comparison

Tags: c++, c, assembly, type-conversion, micro-optimization

So, we all know the C/C++ signed/unsigned comparison rules where `-1 > 2u == true`, and I have a situation where I want to implement 'correct' comparisons efficiently.

My question is, which is more efficient with considerations to as many architectures as people are familiar with. Obviously Intel and ARM have higher weight.

Given:

```
int x;
unsigned int y;
if (x < y) {}
```

Is it better to promote:

```
x < y  =>  (int64)x < (int64)y
```

or is it better to perform 2 comparisons, ie:

```
x < y  =>  (x < 0 || x < y)
```

The former implies a zero-extend, sign-extend, and one comparison+branch, and latter requires no sign-extend operations, but 2 consecutive cmp+branches.
Traditional wisdom suggests that branches are more expensive than sign extends, which will both pipeline, but there is a stall between the extends and the single comparison in the first case, whereas in the second case I can imagine that some architectures might pipeline the 2 comparisons, but then followed by 2 conditional branches?

Another case exists, where the unsigned value is a smaller type than the signed type, which means it can be done with a single zero-extend to the signed type's length, and then a single comparison... in that case, is it preferable to use the extend+cmp version, or is the 2-comparison method still preferred?

Intel? ARM? Others?
I'm not sure if there's a right answer here, but I'd like to hear peoples take's. Low-level performance is hard to predict these days, especially on Intel and increasingly so on ARM.

Edit:

I should add, there is one obvious resolution, where the types are sized equal to the architecture int width; in that case it is obvious that the 2-comparison solution is preferred, since the promotion itself can't be performed efficiently. Clearly my `int` example meets this condition for 32-bit architectures, and you can transpose the thought experiment to `short` for the exercise applied to 32bit platforms.

Edit 2:

Sorry, I forgot the `u` in `-1 > 2u`! >_<

Edit 3:

I want to amend the situation to assume that the result of the comparison an actual branch, and the result is NOT returned as a boolean. This is how I'd prefer the structure look; although this does raise an interesting point that there is another set of permutations when the result is a bool vs a branch.

```
int g;
void fun(int x, unsigned in y) { if((long long)x < (long long)y) g = 10; }
void gun(int x, unsigned in y) { if(x < 0 || x < y) g = 10; }
```

This produces the intended branch typically implied when you encounter an `if` ;)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144743/discussion-on-question-by-manu-evans-correct-unsigned-integer-comparison).

Answer (score 13):

Well, you've correctly typified the situation: C/C++ have no way of doing a full signed int/unsigned int comparison with a single compare.

I would be surprised if promotion to int64 was faster than doing two comparisons. In my experience, compilers are quite good at realizing that a subexpression like that is pure (has no side effects) and thus that there's no need for a second branch. (You can also explicitly opt-out of short circuiting using bitwise-or: `(x < 0) | (x < y)`.) In contrast, my experience is that compilers tend NOT to do much special-case optimization on integers greater than the native word size, so `(int64)x < (int64)y` is quite likely to actually do a full int comparison.

Bottom line, there's no incantation which is guaranteed to produce the best possible machine code on any processor, but for the most common compilers on the most common processors, I would guess that the two-comparison form would be no slower than the promotion-to-int64 form.

EDIT: Some mucking about on Godbolt confirms that on ARM32, GCC puts way too much machinery into the int64 approach. VC does the same on x86. With x64, though, the int64 approach is actually one instruction shorter (since the promotion and 64-bit comparison are trivial). The pipelining might make the actual performance go either way, though. https://godbolt.org/g/wyG4yC

Comment: This is my suspicion too, I expect the 2-compare option is superior on modern systems... but I haven't implemented this before, and I'm sure someone else has, and done the work to time it out, or at least, eye-balled the code for various arch's.

Comment: Fewer instructions does not necessarily mean faster runtime

Comment: @M.M I know, that's precisely why I feel this is a hard question worthy of an answer on SO.

Comment: I should mention, I tested `(x < 0 || x < y)` compared to `(x < 0) | (x < y)`, and the compiler emit identical code. The integer promotion case emits different code. It is surprising to me that the compiler doesn't recognise the pattern and just select the more efficient implementation (possibly with respect to the context).

Comment: Your Godbolt link promotes to `uint64_t`.  The promotion is the same but the comparison predicate is different (and wrong if you want to keep treating the signed number as potentially negative).  AArch64 can do this very efficiently, with sign-extension of an input as part of another instruction.  `cmp   x1, x0, sxtw`  https://godbolt.org/z/iZYYdB.  It's 2019 (and 2017 when you answered this); I think more emphasis on x86-64 would be appropriate; 32-bit x86 is less and less important.  (But 32-bit ARM is still important for low-end stuff)

Answer (score 7):

You have to judge this on case by case basis. There are several reasons why signed types would be used in a program:

1. Because you actually need to have negative numbers in calculations or output.
2. "Sloppy typing", meaning that the programmer just types `int` all over their program without giving it much thought.
3. Accidentally signed. The programmed didn't actually want signed numbers, but ended up with them by accident, either through implicit type promotions or by using integer constants such as `0`, which is of type `int`.

---

In case of 1) then the arithmetic should be carried out with signed arithmetic. You should then convert to the smallest possible type that is needed to contain the maximum expected values.

Suppose for example that a value can have range from `-10000` to `10000`. You will then need to use a 16 bit signed type to represent it. The correct type to use then, platform-independently, is `int_fast16_t`.

The `int_fastn_t` and `uint_fastn_t` types require that the type is at least as large as *n* but the compiler is allowed to pick a larger type if it gives faster code/better alignment.

---

2) is cured by studying `stdint.h` and by stop being lazy. As a programmer, one always needs to consider size and signedness of *every single variable declared in the program*. This has to be done at the point of declaration. Or if you get some manner of revelation later, go back and change the type.

If you don't consider the types carefully, you will with absolute certainty end up writing numerous, often subtle bugs. This is particularly important in C++, which is more picky about type correctness than C.

When "sloppy typing" is used, the actual intended type is most often unsigned rather than signed. Consider this sloppy typing example:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

It makes no sense at all to use signed int here, so why would you? Most likely you are iterating over an array or container and then the correct type to use is `size_t`.

Or alternatively, if you know the maximum size that `n` can hold, for example 100, then you can use the most suitable type for that:

```
for(uint_fast8_t i=0; i<100; i++)
```

---

3) is also cured by studying. Notably the various rules for implicit promotions that exist in these languages, such as *the usual arithmetic conversions* and *integer promotion*.

Comment: "then you can use the most suitable type for that" this is not a good idea, `int` is fastest type on the platform by definition.

Comment: @Slava No it isn't. `int` is a very slow type on all 8 bit computers. And in theory it could also be slower than `long long` on 64 bit computers. The C and C++ standard put no requirement that `int` should correspond to the fastest type, the implementations merely tend to do that out of convenience.

Comment: I am not sure about 8 bit compilers, but `int` is the fastest on Intel and RISC systems I know of. And using smaller sizes there have penalty.

Comment: @Slava Kindly read the answer... I'm not suggesting to use smaller sizes, I'm suggesting to use the fastest possible type that can hold the number. This gives optimal execution speed and memory use both. Unlike `int`, which gives you a signed, non-portable number that may or may not be the fastest one.

Comment: @Slava, do note that `int` is not even necessarily the same type for the very same code compiled with the same tools on the same machine.  I have used compilers that permit its width to be chosen by command-line option.  C and C++ have the types Lundin describes for very good reasons, several of which he addressed.  I don't really comprehend why you argue against using language features that render your code not only provably correct but also fast and portable.

Comment: "why you argue against using language features that render your code not only provably correct" because situation when you say "n can hold, for example 100" is rather exception than rule. I remember fiasco with IBM PC when they said lets use 64K times 10 - that's plenty. And changing data types when your range suddenly changed is not easiest task, and not easy to catch either.

Comment: If you want to micro-optimize the fastest computations and be portable to an 8- or 16-bit compiler, there are the standard types `int_fast8_t`, `int_fast16_t` and `int_fast32_t`.

Comment: @Slava no, he ain't in minority. Most of contemporary C programming is used either for embedded/SoC solutions *and/or* strict low level programming. I also routinely use the exactly same code on both AVR & ARM uC and my x64 PC. You err in the simplest of concepts; namely, you're completely wrong with: the context of your usage of the term "premature optimization", in regards to "int" vs "fastest type", "I doubt somebody would port the same program", "I am afraid your case is very unique", not to mention ""n can hold, for example 100" is rather exception than rule".

Comment: `int_fast32_t` is a 64-bit type in the x86-64 System V ABI.  This is often not what you want for an array or struct; it wastes a lot of space and is only faster when it avoids an extra instruction to sign- or zero-extend.  x86-64 CPUs have cheap zero-extending and sign-extending loads so it only really stops you from using it as a memory source operand when adding to a 64-bit integer/pointer.  TL:DR: The fast types raise the question of *fast for what purpose*; for local vars sure 64-bit can be a good choice.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` - int instead of unsigned can usually optimize better because signed-overflow UB allows the compiler to assume that `i` doesn't wrap around, even if `n` is a wider type.  So the compiler can effectively promote `i` to 64-bit.  If you're going to be sloppy like this, `int` instead of `ptrdiff_t` or `size_t` is arguably better than `unsigned` if you don't need to handle huge containers.  But still agreed that you should really think about what you're doing and probably use an unsigned pointer-width integer type.

Comment: @PeterCordes `fast` types are - obviously - for speed optimization. If you want size optimization or something in between you'd rather go for the `least` types, or just use `uintn_t` with fixed size. `size_t` is also an alternative if you don't care about size but just want to iterate over a array of unknown size etc.

Comment: @Lundin: My point is that an array of `int_fast32_t` will be slower because of cache misses than an array of `int_least32_t`.  And also division is significantly slower for 64-bit integers on Intel hardware.  On AMD hardware before Ryzen, even integer multiply is slower for 64-bit than 32-bit.  So fast32 = int64 can sometimes save an instruction if using it with pointers, but in plenty of other cases is slower.  x86-64 has very efficient support for 32-bit integers; that's the default operand-size.

Answer (score 7):

The two branch version would be certainly slower, but actually none of that is two branch... nor single branch... on x86, if you want a boolean integer result.

For example x86-64 gcc 7.1 will for C++ source:

```
bool compare(int x, unsigned int y) {
    return (x < y); // "wrong" (will emit warning)
}

bool compare2(int x, unsigned int y) {
    return (x < 0 || static_cast<unsigned int>(x) < y);
}

bool compare3(int x, unsigned int y) {
    return static_cast<long long>(x) < static_cast<long long>(y);
}
```

Produce this assembly ([godbolt live demo](https://godbolt.org/g/jtRIE6)).  (Args in EDI and ESI, with potential garbage in upper halves)

```
compare(int, unsigned int):
        cmp     edi, esi
        setb    al
        ret

compare2(int, unsigned int):
        mov     edx, edi
        shr     edx, 31       # sign bit of x
        cmp     edi, esi
        setb    al
        or      eax, edx
        ret

compare3(int, unsigned int):
        movsx   rdi, edi       # sign-extend x
        mov     esi, esi       # zero-extend y
        cmp     rdi, rsi
        setl    al
        ret
```

And if you would try to use these inside more complex code, they would get inlined in 99% cases (where at least the zero-extension would usually optimize away because GCC would already know it wrote the value to a 32-bit register, implicitly zeroing the upper half).

Without profiling it's just guessing, but "by a gut" I would go with `compare3` as "faster", especially when executed out of order inside some code (sort of funny it does the proper 32->64 promotion even for uint argument, while it would require quite some effort to produce code calling that compare with some mess in upper 32b of `esi` ... but it would probably get rid of it when inlined in more complex calculation, where it would note the argument is also uint64 extended already, so the `compare3` is then even simpler+shorter).

... as I said in comment, I don't hit tasks where I would need this, for example I can't imagine to work on something where valid range of data is unknown, so for the task I work on the C/C++ is perfect fit and I appreciate exactly the way how it works (that `<` for signed vs unsigned types is well defined and results in shortest/fastest code, plus warning is emitted to make me as programmer responsible to validate it, and in case of need to change the source appropriately).

Comment: Try it with x86-64 icc. (Seriously, Intel, WTF.)

Comment: I'd like to suggest you structure the benchmark to produce actual branches rather than returning a bool; I think that's the common result of an `if` statement.

Comment: It's interesting to note that I tested with GCC5.4, and the 2-compare code was much worse. It seems that the codegen improved from GCC6.3 -> 7.1.

Comment: @ManuEvans about `if` .. oh, of course I avoid branches whenever reasonably possible, but you are right, that does change the situation a bit... especially if you know you have plenty of negative `int` values. But you have to pick whether you reason in generic way, or you have particular task on mind. For real life particular task I would in the first place try (very hard) to avoid the type mismatch, as that's usually quite possible with real world data, and would simplify everything. If not possible, I would check if you can filter out the negative values as a whole. Code above is last resort

Comment: on x86 `compare2` is probably better  but on x86_64 casting to `long long` like `compare3` might be better

Comment: @ManuEvans When testing with GCC 5.4, did you specify compiler option `-O3`?  Because it seems that if you do, x86-64 GCC 5.4 will produce the same code as x86-64 GCC 7.1, except the first two instructions of `compare2()` use `eax` instead of `edx`.  Similarly, ARM64 GCC 5.4 produces very short functions if `-O3` is specified.

Answer (score 6):

Given the specific setup you presented:

```
int x;
unsigned int y;
```

and your apparent intent to evaluate whether the value of `x` is numerically less than that of `y`, respecting the sign of `x`, I'd be inclined to write it as

```
if ((x < 0) || (x < y)) {}
```

that is, your second alternative.  It expresses the intent clearly, and it is extensible to wider types, as long as the maximum representable value of `y`'s type is at least as large as the maximum representable value of `x`'s type.  Thus,  if you're willing to stipulate that the arguments will have that form then you could even write it as -- avert your eyes, C++ adherents -- a macro.

Converting both arguments to a signed, 64-bit integer type is not a portable solution, because there is no guarantee that that would in fact be a *promotion* from either `int` or `unsigned int`.  It also is not extensible to wider types.

As for relative performance of your two alternative, I doubt there's much difference, but if it matters to you then you would want to write a careful benchmark.  I could imagine the portable alternative requiring one more machine instruction than the other, and I can also imagine it requiring one less.  Only if such comparisons dominate the performance of your application would a single instruction make a noticeable difference one way or the other.

Of course, this is specific to the situation you presented.  If you want to handle mixed signed / unsigned comparisons in either order, for many different types, as sorted out at compile time, then a template-based wrapper could help you with that (and that would moot the question of using a macro), but I take you to be asking specifically about details of the comparison itself.

Comment: I would naturally tend toward that implementation too, except my tests show it produces significantly longer code. I mentioned in my question that with respect to 32bit architectures, you can consider the question relative to 16bit types for the thought experiment. For the sake of the experiment, I assume there is an 'efficient' type for promotion in the promotion case.

Comment: @ManuEvans, relative performance is not solvable as a thought experiment, at least not without specifying architecture details.  As I see it, you must either way load both values into registers.  One implementation then executes up to two conditional jump instructions, whereas the other executes up to two (but probably no more than one) conversion instructions and one conditional jump.  To the extent that this is all hypothetical, I'm not prepared to entertain the infinitely many variations on how the compiler could emit suboptimal code.

Comment: I accept, but I'm still very interested to see this discussion play out, and if any surprises emerge with respect to niche cases.

Answer (score 5):

One portable trick you can do is to check if you can widen both arguments to `intmax_t` from `<stdint.h>`, which is the widest integral type an implementation supports.  You can check `(sizeof(intmax_t) > sizeof(x) && sizeof(intmax_t) >= sizeof(y))` and, if so, do a widening conversion.  This works in the very common case where `int` is 32 bits wide and `long long int` is 64 bits wide.

In C++, you can do clever stuff where you have a safe-comparison template that checks `std::numeric_limits<T>` on its arguments.  Here is one version.  (Compile with `-Wno-sign-compare` on gcc or clang!)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

using std::intmax_t;
using std::uintmax_t;

template<typename T, typename U>
  inline bool safe_gt( T x, U y ) {
    constexpr auto tinfo = std::numeric_limits<T>();
    constexpr auto uinfo = std::numeric_limits<U>();
    constexpr auto maxinfo = std::numeric_limits<intmax_t>();

    static_assert(tinfo.is_integer, "");
    static_assert(uinfo.is_integer, "");

    if ( tinfo.is_signed == uinfo.is_signed )
      return x > y;
    else if ( maxinfo.max() >= tinfo.max() &&
              maxinfo.max() >= uinfo.max() )
      return static_cast<intmax_t>(x) > static_cast<intmax_t>(y);
    else if (tinfo.is_signed) // x is signed, y unsigned.
      return x > 0 && x > y;
    else // y is signed, x unsigned.
      return y < 0 || x > y;      
  }

int main()
{
  assert(-2 > 1U);
  assert(!safe_gt(-2, 1U));
  assert(safe_gt(1U, -2));
  assert(safe_gt(1UL, -2L));
  assert(safe_gt(1ULL, -2LL));
  assert(safe_gt(1ULL, -2));
}
```

It could be made aware of floating-point by changing two lines.

Answer (score 0):

With a little template jiggery-pokery I think we can get the optimal result in all scenarios automatically:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cassert>


template<class T> auto make_unsigned(T i) -> T { return i; }

auto make_unsigned(int i) -> unsigned int {
    assert(i >= 0);
    return static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
}

auto make_unsigned(short i) -> unsigned short {
    assert(i >= 0);
    return static_cast<unsigned short>(i);
}

auto make_unsigned(long long i) -> unsigned long long {
    assert(i >= 0);
    return static_cast<unsigned long long>(i);
}

template<
        class I1,
        class I2,
        std::enable_if_t<(std::is_signed<I1>::value and std::is_signed<I2>::value)
                         or (not std::is_signed<I1>::value and not std::is_signed<I2>::value)>* = nullptr
>
bool unsigned_less(I1 i1, I2 i2) {

    return i1 < i2;
};

template<
        class I1,
        class I2,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<I1>::value and not std::is_signed<I2>::value>* = nullptr
>
bool unsigned_less(I1 i1, I2 i2) {

    return (i1 < 0) or make_unsigned(i1) < i2;
};

template<
        class I1,
        class I2,
        std::enable_if_t<not std::is_signed<I1>::value and std::is_signed<I2>::value>* = nullptr
>
bool unsigned_less(I1 i1, I2 i2) {

    return not (i2 < 0) and i1 < make_unsigned(i2);
};



int main() {

    short a = 1;
    unsigned int b = 2;

    std::cout << unsigned_less(a, b) << std::endl;

    using uint = unsigned int;
    using ushort = unsigned short;
    std::cout << unsigned_less(ushort(1), int(3)) << std::endl;

    std::cout << unsigned_less(int(-1), uint(0)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << unsigned_less(int(1), uint(0)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree, the implementation to the resolution of this question will look something like this, but your answer doesn't address the question; is int promotion, or multiple comparisons more efficient in the particular case? You have rolled with multiple comparisons, but that doesn't address the question.

Comment: @ManuEvans the optimiser will see through all attempts to manually optimise anyway. It's unlikely to be worth hand-optimising

Comment: It does not. Optimiser emits the 2 cases distinctly on all compilers I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Andrei Alexandrescus keynote at the recent D conference in Berlin on Design by Introspection.

In it he shows how to design a checked int class at DESIGN time and one of the features he comes up with is exactly this - how to compare signed and unsigned.

Basically you need to perform 2 comparisons

*If (signed_var < 0) then return unsigned_var 
else promote / cast signed_var to unsigned_var and then compare*